# CSVHelper remove space and dashes from headers

Tags: csvhelper

I have a project where the CSV file header has both spaces and dashes in the column header names.

The headers look like this:

```
First Name, Last Name, E-mail Address, Phone
```

I am successful in removing the spaces using the following code:

```
PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header.Header, @"\s", string.Empty)
```

I have been unsuccessful in adding the "-" to the regex to strip out both spaces and dashes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!

I was able to resolve the issue with the following regex:

```
PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace(header.Header, @"[\s-]+", string.Empty).ToLower()
```

I had tried variations of "[\s-]+" and kept running into issues. This variation provided the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I like to extend the string class for this:

```
public static string RemoveWhitespaceAndDash(this string input)
{
    return new string(input.ToCharArray()
                .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c == '-')
                .ToArray());
}
```

In this example it is removing both whitespace and '-'. You can easily see how to add any other characters. I prefer to stay away from regex when I don't really need.

Once you have extended the string class then you can Use it like:

```
string cleanStr = Header.header.RemoveWhitespaceAndDash();
```